# SAPUI5: Unable to NavTo Defined Page with Error (Control with ID layout could not be found - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target)

Tags: javascript, xml, navigation, sapui5, manifest.json

I have write some code navigate to the next page in SAPUI5.
It works in most of my other SAPUI5 application. However, 
when comes to this application. It does not work for me.

I have spend 1 day to find out the solution but it seems does 
not work for me.

It always shown me the following error when I nav to the page.

```
Control with ID layout could not be found - EventProvider sap.m.routing.Target
```

The following is my source code

Manifest.JSON

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "viewPath": "hackathon.customer.view",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "controlId": "layout",
            "clearControlAggregation": false
        },
        "routes": [
            {
                "name": "RouteApp",
                "pattern": "RouteApp",
                "target": [
                    "TargetApp"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "ExtensibilityConfiguration",
                "name": "ExtensibilityConfiguration",
                "target": [
                    "ExtensibilityConfiguration"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "targets": {
            "TargetApp": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearControlAggregation": false,
                "viewName": "App"
            },
            "ExtensibilityConfiguration": {
                "viewName": "ExtensibilityConfiguration",
                "viewId": "Extensibility-Configuration",
                "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller.js

```
    addNewExtensionItemPress: function()
    {
        this._oRouter.navTo("ExtensibilityConfiguration", {}, false);
    },
```

View.xml

```
<mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="hackathon.customer.controller.App" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <App>
        <pages>
            <Page title="{i18n>title}">
                <content>
                    <Panel>
                        <f:SimpleForm id="idSimpleForm" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" title="Customer details" labelSpanXL="3" labelSpanL="3"
                            labelSpanM="3" labelSpanS="12" adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="4" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1"
                            columnsL="1" columnsM="1" singleContainerFullSize="false">
                            <f:content>
                                <Label text="Customer"/>
                                <ComboBox id="idComboBox" items="{newspageModel>/Customer}" selectionChange="onSelChange">
                                    <core:Item key="{newspageModel>CUSTOMER_NO}" text="{newspageModel>CUSTOMER_NO}"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <Label text="Customer No."/>
                                <Input id="idCustNo" value="{model>/CUSTOMER_NO}" enabled="false"/>
                                <Label text="Customer Name"/>
                                <Input id="idCustName" value="{model>/CUSTOMER_NAME}" enabled="false"/>
                                <Label text="Address line 1"/>
                                <Input id="idCustAdd" value="{model>/ADDRESS_LINE1}" enabled="false"/>
                                <Label text="Address line 2"/>
                                <Input id="idCustAddt" value="{model>/ADDRESS_LINE2}" enabled="false"/>
                                <Label text="Private No."/>
                                <Input id="idPrivNo" value="{model>/PRIVATE_NO}" enabled="false" />
                            </f:content>
                        </f:SimpleForm>
                        <f:SimpleForm id="Extension_Form" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanXL="3" labelSpanL="3"
                            labelSpanM="3" labelSpanS="12" adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="4" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1"
                            columnsL="1" columnsM="1" singleContainerFullSize="false">
                            <f:content>
                                <core:Fragment fragmentName="hackathon.customer.view.fragment.CustomerExtension" type="XML"/>
                            </f:content>
                        </f:SimpleForm>
                    </Panel>
                    <Button id="ExtConBtn"  width="200px" icon="sap-icon://add"  text="Add New Field" press="addNewExtensionItemPress" />
                </content>
                <footer>
                    <Bar  id="BottomBar">
                        <contentRight>
                            <Button id="edit" text="Edit" press="handleEditPress"/>
                            <Button id="save" text="Save" visible="false" press="handleSavePress"/>
                        </contentRight>
                    </Bar>
                </footer>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: @MatthijsMennens I have included my view.xml.

Comment: @ChanYoongHon Check you rootView you don't have a control with id="layout".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
 <App id="layout">
```

Comment: In rootview id might be missing.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you so much. Really save me a lot of time.